# build gradle for hibernate usage in intellj

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, gradle

hey i d like to know how i manage to build build gradle in intellj.
i know how to do it in eclipse an it works fine.
i want to connect a sqlite db to intellj like i do it in eclipse so i can insert soemthing over hibernate.
this is how i do it in eclipse:
i make a new gradle project
then i write my buildgradle file
[image]

then i go rightclick on build.gradle and select "gradle" and then "refresh gradle"

now this works without eclipse telling me there was an error
[image]

i drag and drop my db here (name of db: spiel.db)
[image]

and then i write my hibernate.cfg.xml:
[image]

and now when i run my main everything is fine...

now i want to do the exact thing in intellj:

so i do new gradle project and then i write the same buildgradle file
then i press build
[image]

and now intellj is complaining about my code
[image]

did i forget something?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some import problem, do you have hibernate support on? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/overview-of-hibernate-support.html